# Pure css3 table row overlay on hover

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to make a simple table with following structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>E-mail</td>
        <td>Role</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Hetfield</td>
        <td>Owner</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td><!-- checkbox --></td>
        <td colspan="2"> <!-- link to details --></td>
        <td><!-- buttons: edit, remove --></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, after a row with data there is hidden row with controls, which should "replace" exact row on mouse hover, and disappear when mouse is outside. Tried to do this with position: relative on row and absolute on hidden + display:none/ block on hover, but failed. :(

Comment: Please paste your code and possibly a link to a demo so that we may help you.

Comment: A little hint: "display: none" in first instance is not bad but redisplaying with "display: block" as most would try will not work here because you have a table and <td> and <th> elements require: "display: table-cell" and <tr> tag requires: "display: table-row"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mattrick/fPyLR/

I guess browsers nowadays eliminate <tr> inside <trs>, so i can't position absolute inside relative visible tr. :(

Answer (score 1):

Could you add "action cells" in every tr and simply show/hide those when hovering?

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>E-mail</td>
        <td>Role</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="info-td">1</td>
        <td class="info-td">James</td>
        <td class="info-td">Hetfield</td>
        <td class="info-td">Owner</td>
        <td class="action-td">checkbox</td>
        <td class="action-td" colspan="2">details --></td>
        <td class="action-td">buttons</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
.action-td {
    display: none;
}
tr:hover > .info-td {
    display: none;
}
tr:hover > .action-td {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V9Qk7/

Comment: As far as I see, it's currently best option, so I'll use it. However, ideally I'd like to replace rows, but thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I really expect this a solution! I've try it only in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                border: 0 transparent none;
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
                background-color: transparent;
                font-family: monospace;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 12px;
                text-align: left;
                text-transform: none;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            table{
                display: table;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            table>thead{display: table-header-group}
            table>tbody{display: table-row-group}
            table>tfoot{display: table-footer-group}
            table>thead>tr,
            table>tbody>tr,
            table>tfoot>tr{display: table-row}
            table>thead>tr>th,
            table>tbody>tr>th,
            table>tfoot>tr>th,
            table>thead>tr>td,
            table>tbody>tr>td,
            table>tfoot>tr>td{
                display: table-cell;
                padding: 5px;
            }



            table.list>thead>tr{
                border-bottom: 2px rgba(120, 120, 120, 1) solid;
            }
            table.list>thead>tr>th,
            table.list>thead>tr>td,
            table.list>tbody>tr>th:first-child,
            table.list>tbody>tr>td:first-child,
            table.list>tbody>tr>th:first-child>span:first-of-type,
            table.list>tbody>tr>td:first-child>span:first-of-type{
                font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            table.list>thead>tr>th:first-child,
            table.list>thead>tr>td:first-child,
            table.list>tbody>tr>th:first-child,
            table.list>tbody>tr>td:first-child,
            table.list>tfoot>tr>th:first-child,
            table.list>tfoot>tr>td:first-child{
                border-right: 2px rgba(120, 120, 120, 1) solid;
            }
            table.list>thead>tr>th:not(:first-child),
            table.list>thead>tr>td:not(:first-child),
            table.list>tbody>tr>th:not(:first-child),
            table.list>tbody>tr>td:not(:first-child),
            table.list>tfoot>tr>th:not(:first-child),
            table.list>tfoot>tr>td:not(:first-child){
                border-left: 1px rgba(220, 220, 220, 1) solid;
            }
            table.list>tbody>tr:nth-child(even){
                background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1);
            }

            table.list>tbody>tr a{
                display: inline;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: rgba(20, 120, 220, 1);
            }

            /**  I think the most important part of CSS starts here  **/
            table.list>tbody>tr>th.rotation>span,
            table.list>tbody>tr>td.rotation>span{
                display: inline-block;

                transition-duration: .7s;
                -o-transition-duration: .7s;
                -moz-transition-duration: .7s;
                -webkit-transition-duration: .7s;
            }
            /** I prefered to apply absolute layout on :first-of-type because it seem to take less place than other **/
            table.list>tbody>tr>th.rotation>span:first-of-type,
            table.list>tbody>tr>td.rotation>span:first-of-type{
                position: absolute;
            }
            table.list>tbody>tr:hover>th.rotation>span:last-of-type,
            table.list>tbody>tr:hover>td.rotation>span:last-of-type,
            table.list>tbody>tr>th.rotation>span:first-of-type,
            table.list>tbody>tr>td.rotation>span:first-of-type{
                opacity: 1;
            }
            table.list>tbody>tr:hover>th.rotation>span:first-of-type,
            table.list>tbody>tr:hover>td.rotation>span:first-of-type,
            table.list>tbody>tr>th.rotation>span:last-of-type,
            table.list>tbody>tr>td.rotation>span:last-of-type{
                opacity: 0;
            }
            table.list>tbody>tr:hover>th.rotation>span:first-of-type,
            table.list>tbody>tr:hover>td.rotation>span:first-of-type{
                transform: rotateY(90deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        #
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        email
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        role
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        carreer
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="rotation">
                        <span>1</span>
                        <span>
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        James
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Hetfield
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Owner
                    </td>
                    <td class="rotation">
                        <span>
                            Acount carreer
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <a href="#">Show</a>
                            <a href="#">Édit</a>
                            <a href="#">Delete</a>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="rotation">
                        <span>2</span>
                        <span>
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        James
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Hetfield
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Owner
                    </td>
                    <td class="rotation">
                        <span>
                            Acount carreer
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <a href="#">Show</a>
                            <a href="#">Édit</a>
                            <a href="#">Delete</a>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="rotation">
                        <span>3</span>
                        <span>
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        James
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Hetfield
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Owner
                    </td>
                    <td class="rotation">
                        <span>
                            Acount carreer
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <a href="#">Show</a>
                            <a href="#">Édit</a>
                            <a href="#">Delete</a>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, indeed this is very close to solution. Unfortunately, the content of table is dynamic and I can't style spans separately. I need the most general, data-independent, css3 & html solution possible.

Comment: When you say **content is generated dynamically** did you means there are some cases where you'll not need to add **span** element twice? Thus update selector by adding `:not(only-of-child)` when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and modify its to fit your needs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style type="text/css">
            tr{
                display: table-row;
                transition-duration: .7s;
                -o-transition-duration: .7s;
                -moz-transition-duration: .7s;
                -webkit-transition-duration: .7s;
            }
            tr.hidden{
                opacity: 0;
            }
            table:hover tr.hidden{
                opacity: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Number</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>E-mail</td>
                <td>Role</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>James</td>
                <td>Hetfield</td>
                <td>Owner</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hidden">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="rich"/>
                    <label for="rich">Rich ?</label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <a href="#">Show</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#">Édit</a>
                    <a href="#">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is that it doesn't overlay previous row. And I need to do that.

Comment: Did you want to overlay all preceding rows? Or just the first previous one.

Comment: Maybe I'll show on image:
[http://i.cubeupload.com/B0kNl1.png](http://i.cubeupload.com/B0kNl1.png)

It's done on overlaying divs, but the best point about it is that I can set "opacity" on some elements and see what's under my overlay layer.